# Spring Integration - need advice

Tags: architecture, spring-integration

I am quite new to Spring Integration and need to figure out solution in my work.

What I need to do is:
- Provide polling mechanism from db. 
- Should be able to enable/disable polling when certain condition occurs 
- Need timeout for polling (for example if status doesnt change for 5 min minutes do stomething) 
- Need to pass data to polling mechanism

Basically its all what I need. I was thinking about using Spring's **task:scheduled-tasks** but I cant see option for manually enabling/disabling task and setting timeout.
Data that needs to be passed to polling mechanism can be stored in Spring bean. Could you guys advise if I am stepping into right direction or should I try other aproach?

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple example of how to poll a database with spring integration

```
    <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter 
            id="jdbcPoller" channel="jdbc.poll.channel"
            data-source="dataSource" query="select count(*) from test_table">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="500" task-executor="pollTaskExecutor"/>
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="jdbc.poll.channel"/>
```

if you wanted to stop it conditionally, you could do something like this

```
        //stop the polling
    AbstractEndpoint poller = context.getBean("jdbcPoller",AbstractEndpoint.class);
    poller.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `task:scheduled-tasks`, and you'll need to implement the bits you want, as spring doesn't provide all the features you want OOTB.

- The disable bit, can be done by the task checking if it was disabled, and thus not do anything.
- About the time out, your code needs to figure out what does "status doesn't change" and "do something".
- Need to pass data to polling mechanism: the polling mechanism can load the data it requires, or read it from a source (queue, shared object, etc).

Comment: Thx, Augusto for your reply. However I dont want scheduled task to be running idle. I would rather prefer switching it on and off if polling is not needed. Question with timeout is does spring handle timeouts in that case or I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Integration, you can use a `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter/>`. You can start/stop it using the `Lifecycle methods` `isRunning()`, `start()`, `stop()`.

Or, you can send messages to a `<control-bus/>` to start/stop.

There are a number of ways to detect no activity (e.g. using JMX to look at the message count for the channel etc).